# IMPORTFROMWEB() , splitResult=TRUE not working for this table?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

=IMPORTFROMWEB is a custom function for google sheets developed by
https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/documentation/

It helps me load data from dynamic html to a spreadsheet. (any other solution for excel or google sheets also works)

Here I'm loading a table.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dh7KZ91FeqzvTh2BwzB6WOmfTUTN4FoGIf_c4ZrfdHk/edit?usp=sharing
code is in A6 & A15.

But the function returns everything in on cell instead of separating them. splitResult doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IMPORTFROMWEB, you will need to indicate the path for each column of the table
Just follow this example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using a different source than Morninstar?  Yahoo is pretty scrapable with normal IMPORTHTML().  That is, without a custom function.

I put htis formula on a new tab in your sheet and it seems to work ok...

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MCSMX/holdings?p=MCSMX","table",1)
```